# Are localised versions of questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I have a question about my credit limit and score, which [has an answer for the US side of things](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/73084/if-i-increase-my-credit-limit-will-my-credit-score-go-up) (and [a related but different question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/79243/is-there-a-catch-on-my-increased-credit-limit)). I am in the UK, an credit score considerations might be different here for all I know.

If I were to ask, would it be closed as a duplicate, or is it reasonable to ask?

I am interested in the specific answer here of course; but also the general case where things might be *similar-but-different* between regions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Localized questions are fine. In fact, for many questions here, we encourage a country code. With no country specified, the answer will often be US-centric.

Your question should not be closed as a duplicate, unless of course, a member finds it's been answered specific to UK.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification- elsewhere I've seen the approach "If it has the same answer/solution it's a duplicate (even if the *reasons* are slightly different)", so this is useful to know. Hopefully I've done a reasonably good job of dupe-checking but we'll see :)

Comment: I'm ignorant of the rules for scoring in the UK, and making the assumption that it's not identical to US.